# Match a table in R and return value from row

Tags: r, matching

I have a column of data, `state_key` and info about it stored in `distance_key` I would like to scan `state_key` for matches with `state_m` and when there's a match I would like it to return in `distance_key`

Like so:

```
   state_key distance_key state_m distance_key 
1    CA       100            NC        120
2    NC       120            OH        160
3    MA       130
4    OH       160
```

When you use `match()` it'll tell me if there is one, but I need more than that.

Comment: `with(df, distance_key[as.character(state_key) == as.character(state_m)])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User the faster and more efficient package - data.table:

```
install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)
```

store the list of states that you are looking for in a data table

```
list.states <- as.data.table(state_m)
setnames(list.states,1,"STATE_CODE") # give some name to your column eg: STATE_CODE
setkey(list.states,STATE_CODE) # merging would be done on STATE_CODE
```

the entire data set of State code and distances should be stored as a data table

```
dt.state.key <- as.data.table(state_key) 
setnames(dt.state.key,1,"STATE_CODE") # same column name as in the list to be matched
setkey(dt.state.key,STATE_CODE) # merging would be done on this column

result <- merge(list.states,dt.state.key,all=F) # inner join (all=F) gives the match
```

Comment: Almost worked, but 
'the entire data set of State code and distances should be stored as a data table'

This only returned the states that matched by not the corresponding distances.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
mydf[ mydf$state_key %in% state_m,]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a data frame of all rows that match an entry in `state_m` and their corresponding `distance_key` try the following:

```
df[df$state_key %in% state_m, cbind("state_key" , "distance_key")]
```

If you merely want the corresponding `distance_key` values in a vector, you can more succinctly return:

```
df[df$state_key %in% state_m, "distance_key"]
```

And if state_m is a single value and not a vector of values use:

```
df[df$state_key == state_m, "distance_key"]
```

Comment: `df[df$state_key %in% state_m, cbind("state_key" , "distance_key"))`

There seemed to be problems with this in that synax is off,  `[ ]` do not close

I also get a unexpected   `,` after `state_m`

Comment: @PhillipBlack You are absolutely right. Corrections in the edits above. Made a bunch of ]'s into )'s.

Comment: Hmmm when I ran this I got a result of 0 obs and 2 variables

Comment: @PhillipBlack What does your state_m look like? Have you verified it's of the same type as df$state_key?

Comment: Got it. I just had to `$` after `%in%`